# Is it correct to combine component's react state with redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

In our application we use redux and store out the whole application state in a global state. But I'm just interested is it correct to store some components's data also in own state? Thus we will have part of data in a global redux state and part of data in component's own state.

Please share your thoughts about it.

Comment: This is a little open. What are you trying to do with that component?

Comment: My component is a form with some fields and CRUD table

Comment: And what does it do that could use some state?

Comment: When adding the new table rows they not in a database yet. So the user may add three ones and submit a bunch of data. For these purposes I thought to use component's state

Comment: If they add the rows without saving and then leave and return, are they expecting them to still be there?

Comment: No, if the user leaves the form they should disappear

Comment: Then it might be a good idea for your component to be stateful! You get the state clearing for free with it and you don't need to worry about writing reducers for handling the new data.

Comment: BUT it might be an idea to split the stateful bit out into a parent container component and pull out as many stateless components as possible, just to minimise the impact of that state.

Comment: I agree with @christopher

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Redux: Should all component states be kept in Redux Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328056/react-redux-should-all-component-states-be-kept-in-redux-store)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's not wrong to combine local state and redux-state, but it's not fully correct also. It depends your needs.

In some of my components, displayed values and redux-state values are a bit different. For example usage of my custom `NumberField`, values are displayed as `123.123,567`  but binded to redux-state as `123,123.456`.

In addition, you can use local state to manipulate some values or hold some helper states etc.

**If It's not problem to trace redux-state and your business flow, feel free about using local state, but be careful!**

There is another discussion [here](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/redux-and-global-state-vs-local-state/4187)

Answer (score 0):

Combining the two kinda defeats the purpose of using Redux. It's there to serve data from it's own 'state'. The best way to use Redux is to only listen for the data that you need and is narrowed down to the nearest parent. That way your app will be more performant because it's not re-rendering every time data somewhere else re-renders.