# Should I use separate reducers for working with a publication list and a single publication?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm learning Redux and recently met the situation when I don't really sure wether I need to use the second reducer to fetch, to like publication and so on.

I read a documentation and found the following  rule: "In a React + Redux app, your global state should go in the Redux store, and your local state should stay in React components".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reducer function is what is used to operate over a conceptual "unit of state", e.g. a group of related fields/properties that are often updated/rendered/etc together.

If you have a state slice that holds an array of publication objects then you can operate directly on a single publication, sans any additional state slices/reducers. The downside to this is that you are directly making changes to the "source of truth".

Suppose you had a UI/UX where the user could *edit* a publication and *only after* submitting the changes is the publication updated in state. For this a second state slice/reducer to hold the *editable* copy could be used.

The takeaway here should be that each state slice/reducer should only contain and operate over a group of ***related*** fields/properties with a common purpose. How you decide to break up and group your app state is largely subjective and up to you and the app's needs and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret Drew Reese's answer as suggesting that both the publication list reducer and the single publication reducer could be managed by Redux (global state). To follow up on the part of the original question that addresses global state (Redux store) versus local state (React components), the Redux documentation asks: [Do I have to put all my state into Redux? Should I ever use React's useState or useReducer?](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#do-i-have-to-put-all-my-state-into-redux-should-i-ever-use-reacts-usestate-or-usereducer). The documentation answers these questions by saying:

> There is no "right" answer for this.
> **Using local component state is fine.**

The docs also offer links to other relevant articles and these *common rules of thumb for determining what kind of data should be put into Redux* (global state):

> - Do other parts of the application care about this data?
> - Do you need to be able to create further derived data based on this original data?
> - Is the same data being used to drive multiple components?
> - Is there value to you in being able to restore this state to a given point in time (ie, time travel debugging)?
> - Do you want to cache the data (ie, use what's in state if it's already there instead of re-requesting it)?
> - Do you want to keep this data consistent while hot-reloading UI components (which may lose their internal state when swapped)?

If these rules of thumb were considered in the context of the state of a single publication, the question:

> Do other parts of the application care about this data?

Could read as:
*Do other parts of the application care about the number of likes this single publication has?*

- if "yes": use a Redux (global) reducer
- if "no": use React.useReducer (local) and fetch the number of likes in React.useEffect.

---

Although today it is [recommended to use Redux Toolkit](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) these older StackOverflow questions also address your concern:

- [Combining React local state with Redux global state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367559), and
- [React-Redux: Should all component states be kept in Redux Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328056).