# How do I properly use Redux for complicated dashboard app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

All YouTube videos I found and the official docs show how to use Redux for a *very specific task*, like a todo list app. The example mostly have *only one type of data* (e.g. todo tasks).

Unfortunately, i have not found a guide how to deal with the following problem:

I have a dashboard app, which displays many different types of data (over 20; contacts data, customer data, invoice data, file information etc.). I have started using Redux like shown in the docs.

I created actions for each type of data. For example:

```
FETCH_CONTACTS
CREATE_CONTACT
DELETE CONTACT

FETCH_INVOICES
...
```

My question is, how do I handle my data? Because of the fact, that I have over 20 types of data, invoices should only be loaded, if the user opens `/invoices`, contacts only if he opens `/contacts` etc. Also what is the best why to implement a filter (search), which gets handled by the server, since a single data type can have over 1000 entries.

Moreover, how do I manage authentication in Redux? Should I have auth actions like:

```
TRY_LOGIN
LOGOUT
...
```

Comment: This is the thing with Redux and these kind of stores, they let you do anything you want. You can start by asking yourself: [Should everything be in redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35328056/1218980)

Comment: There's also a FAQ entry about [organizing your Redux store's state](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state).

Comment: My personal rule of thumb is: Anything that relates to business logic should be kept in the store, with actions handling the logic. Anything related to UI/UX is in the components state, except some specific global state of your UI that is shared across the app.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Yes, I have already decided, that only business logic should be handled by Redux. My question is more about how to use Redux (or with middlewares) to only load the data i need. And how to handle authentication.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's kind of 2 questions that are way too broad and opinion-based for Stack overflow.

Comment: You can have 20 separate reducers for each type of data. And keep a common structure for all of the reducers. Like `{arr:[], obj:{}, stats:{}}`. and create actions like `updateArr`, `updateObj` & `updateStats`. Finlay, you can keep this structure for all of the reducers to make the process easier.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Do you know any resources which cover this topics? Any open-source project I could take as an example?

Comment: Have you seen  this example? https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos

Comment: Asking for examples and/or off-site resources is also off-topic for Stack overflow. Authentication and data management is much more than just Redux and can span across a huge part of an app, so it boils down to _"how to manage authentication in a frontend app"_. Once you've found a way for your use-case you're happy with, mixing Redux in becomes trivial.

Comment: @DominikTargosz I literally wrote that I mostly saw examples with todo lists.  My question is how do I use Redux if I have not only one class of data (todo tasks), but multiple.

Comment: Even with the todo list example, there's a thousand way you could manage the data, depending on your use-case, constraints and preferences.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Well you started posting off-site resources, so I thought it was ok. Also, thank you for your comments, but saying the question is too complex to ask does not really help.

Comment: I tried to share the rules while still pointing you in the right direction, but you won't get official answers here. I'm pushing the limit on what comments are for.